# Azure Cosmos DB .NET SDK - background request every 5 minutes?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using ASP.NET 7 with Cosmos DB SDK Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos 3.32.2 in Direct connection mode like this:

```cs
CosmosClientBuilder clientBuilder = new CosmosClientBuilder(cosmosDbEndpoint, tokenCredential)
                .WithConnectionModeDirect()
                .WithContentResponseOnWrite(false)
                .WithThrottlingRetryOptions(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), 9)
                .WithCustomSerializer(new CosmosSystemTextJsonSerializer(Globals.JsonSerializerOptions))
                .AddCustomHandlers(appInsightsRequestHandler);

_dbClient = clientBuilder.Build();
_container = _dbClient.GetContainer(databaseName, containerName);
```

Now I observed in Application Insights, that there seems to be some call to the database every 5 minutes - without any interaction on the API etc. It doesn't give me any real hint what the call is doing. But it takes over 200ms - which is really slow.

Does anybody know what this call is about?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is by design. You will see the call is an HTTP GET to the account endpoint.

This call is made outside of any operation (so it doesn't affect your operational latency), and it refreshes the account information (available regions, configuration) to proactively detect changes in the available regions.

More details on https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/troubleshoot-sdk-availability

Comment: ah thanks, good to know! the only confusing this is that AppInsights had those calls under the same operationId as some previous call to my API - which indicated some correlation.

Comment: That is interesting, might be that it is attempting to automatically correlate operations? The refresh does not happen inline with operations, it's a background loop with a Task.Delay

Comment: It looks a bit like it attached to the last operation (API call) that was coming in - until there is another call. But thats just a very rough guess by looking at the data I'm seeing. Ideally of course it shouldnt attach at all

Comment: Agree. I am not sure how AppInsights is coming up with the attachment/relationship. On the SDK we just do a background Task and it sends the request from there.